# chart.redraw() not working after setting event-line

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, morris.js, bootstrap-slider

I'm using the morris.js chart along with the bootstrap slider.

**What I want to do:**
If the slider is moved, I want to insert an event-line into the chart at the position of the sliders value. Nothing special.

**The problem:**
The chart isn't redrawing after setting the event. When inserting new data, the chart will be redrawn automatically. So I tried refreshing (to check for correct syntax) by passing the existing data to the chart again like this:

```
chart.setData(chart.options.data);
```

*This is working!* The new event gets drawn into the chart. Unfortunately this has a bad performance as the chart is redrawing all the data.

The documentation says there is `chart.redraw()`. It's just not working for me. Maybe someone of you can find out why.

***Just run the snippet and switch the radio-buttons to test both methods and you'll see the problem.***

```js
// Chart creation - not interesting
var chart = new Morris.Line({
  element: 'chart',
  ymin: 0,
  ymax: 100,
  gridIntegers: true,
  parseTime:false,
  // Will be set below
  data: [  ],
  xkey: 'position',
  ykeys: ['value'],
  labels: ['Value'],
  hideHover: "always",
  pointSize: 0,
  continuousLine: false,
  goalStrokeWidth: 3,
  axes: true,
  grid: true,
  numLines: 6,
  eventLineColors: [ "red" ],
  smooth: true
});

// Inserting some values
var values = [101]
for(i = 1; i <= 100; i += 1) {
    var x = 100/(Math.pow((i-50), 2)+4);
    values.push({ position: i, value: x });
}
chart.setData(values);

// Create slider
$('#slider').slider({
  tooltip: 'never',
  tooltip_position:'left',
  height: 300,
  length: 300,
});

// If the slider moves, I want to set its value as an event-line
$("#slider").on("slideStop", function(slideEvt) {
    chart.options.events = [ slideEvt.value ];

    // Check inserting-data VS chart.redraw()
    // Both should work... chart.redraw() isnt.
    if(document.getElementById('insert').checked)
        chart.setData(chart.options.data);
    else if(document.getElementById('redraw').checked)
        chart.redraw();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.5.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.5.1.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Bootstrap slider -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.7.2/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.7.2/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css">

<div id="chart" style="height: 150px;width:500px;"></div>
<form action="">
    <input checked="true" id="insert" type="radio" name="refreshMethod"> Insert (working)<br>
    <input id="redraw" type="radio" name="refreshMethod"> Redraw (not working)<br>
</form>
<input id="slider" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="50"/>
```

I appreciate every help in here. Thank you very much!

**Important edit:**
As soon as I can set a bounty (+1 hour) I'll do so. A very important additional part of this question is how to bind the slider to the single chart-event without lagging around. Currently the performance is very low when using the `slide` event instead of `slideStop`.

Comment: "The documentation says there is `chart.redraw()`. " - could you point out where/which document you are making reference to? I could not find it (see links in my answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because internally `chart.events` is not being set when you call `chart.redraw()`. This property is set inside `setData` with the line `this.events = this.options.events`.

To correct for this: In your code use `chart.events = [val]` rather than `chart.options.events = [val];`

Personally, I'd set them both in case `setData` is called again, but that's up to you.

So in your demo:

```
...
else if(document.getElementById('redraw').checked) {
    chart.events = [ slideEvt.value ];
    chart.redraw();
}
```

**EDIT:**

Added a `chart.quickRedraw` function. This removes unnecessary recalculations from the redraw function (refer to the commented out code for what is now excluded):

```
chart.quickRedraw = function() {
      this.raphael.clear();
      //this._calc();
      this.drawGrid();
      //this.drawGoals();
      this.drawEvents();
      this.draw();      
};
```

Demo has been updated with the third option.

```js
// Chart creation - not interesting
var chart = new Morris.Line({
  element: 'chart',
  ymin: 0,
  ymax: 100,
  gridIntegers: true,
  parseTime:false,
  // Will be set below
  data: [  ],
  xkey: 'position',
  ykeys: ['value'],
  labels: ['Value'],
  hideHover: "always",
  pointSize: 0,
  continuousLine: false,
  goalStrokeWidth: 3,
  axes: true,
  grid: true,
  numLines: 6,
  eventLineColors: [ "red" ],
  smooth: true
});

// Inserting some values
var values = [101]
for(i = 1; i <= 100; i += 1) {
    var x = 100/(Math.pow((i-50), 2)+4);
    values.push({ position: i, value: x });
}
chart.setData(values);

// Create slider
$('#slider').slider({
  tooltip: 'never',
  tooltip_position:'left',
  height: 300,
  length: 300,
});

// If the slider moves, I want to set its value as an event-line
$("#slider").on("slideStop", function(slideEvt) {
    chart.options.events = [ slideEvt.value ];

    // Check inserting-data VS chart.redraw()
    // Both should work... chart.redraw() isnt.
    if(document.getElementById('insert').checked)
        chart.setData(chart.options.data);
    else if(document.getElementById('redraw').checked) {
        chart.events = [ slideEvt.value ];
        chart.redraw();
    } else if(document.getElementById('quickerRedraw').checked) {
        chart.events = [ slideEvt.value ];
        chart.quickRedraw();
    }
});

chart.quickRedraw = function() {
      this.raphael.clear();
      //this._calc();
      this.drawGrid();
      //this.drawGoals();
      this.drawEvents();
      this.draw();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.5.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.5.1.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Bootstrap slider -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.7.2/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.7.2/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css">

<div id="chart" style="height: 150px;width:500px;"></div>
<form action="">
    <input checked="true" id="insert" type="radio" name="refreshMethod"> Insert (working)<br>
    <input id="redraw" type="radio" name="refreshMethod"> Redraw (working)<br>
    <input id="quickerRedraw" type="radio" name="refreshMethod"> Quicker Redraw<br>
</form>
<input id="slider" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="50"/>
```

Comment: I've updated the answer to include an alternative faster redraw function, by removing some of the unneeded `redraw` code. Refer to the edit for details